# LibGDX using FBO in shader as a mask

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, fragment-shader

I'm trying to do 2d lighting on android using libgdx. So, I've already done the "mathy" part, so `drawMask()` uses `PolygonSpriteBatch` to draw a grayscale mask, which i intend to use as a lighting mask. I'm drawing the mask to the screen, then rendering it to FBO, then passing FBO to a shader, which simply multiplies the color by sampling the FBO texture. The problem is, the texture which i need to draw appears black. When I remove the whole FBO drawing block, it is drawn normally. I'm using Scene2D

```
public void draw()
    drawMask();
    fbo.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawMask();
    fbo.end();

    fboRegion.getTexture().bind(1);
    batch.setShader(shaderProgram);
    shaderProgram.setUniformi("u_mask", 1);

    batch.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    batch.draw(sampleTexture, 0, 0);

    batch.setShader(null);
}
...
FrameBuffer fbo;
TextureRegion fboRegion;
ShaderProgram shaderProgram;
...
LightingActor() {
    ...
    fbo = new FrameBuffer(
        Pixmap.Format.RGB565, 
        Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
        Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),
        false
    );
    fboRegion = new TextureRegion(fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
    shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec4 v_light;
void main() {
    v_color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
    v_light = gl_Position;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec4 v_light;
uniform sampler2D u_mask;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_mask, v_light.xy) * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
}
```